# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS + Windows 10 w/ shared storage on one SSD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I've been trying to better understand the possibilities of dual booting OSs on a single SSD. I'm interested in most effectively partitioning my main drive to include both Linux and Windows, while having the remainder (if possible) as shared storage.

I've read a few articles about having multiple SSDs for the OSs but a single drive for shared storage. What I'm trying to do, ideally, is use only one SSD.

Does anyone have any links to a guide on doing something like this? Is it even possible, or practical? If not, is my best bet just deciding how much of each OSs I'm going to be using and create two partitions instead of 3?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? And either way make sure in Windows to turn off its fast start up (always on hibernation). That keeps all partitions mounted and then any write from Linux is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows 10 first by creating a 2 partitions C: (for the system) and D: for storage and leave a space unallocated for Ubuntu.

for example if you have 500Gb you can install Windows 10 on 200Gb partition and create a 150GB partition for Storage (NTFS) and leave 150Gb unallocated.

Once you've done installing Windows 10, start Ubuntu live CD and chose install alongside windows 10 (it will be installed on the unallocated space) after finishing the installation you will end up with Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot and a partition in between where you can put you stuff.
you can set this partition on Ubuntu to be mounted on startup using a tool on Ubuntu called 'Disks'

Hope this answers your question.